What is small arch between two notes and how to play it?
I'm relatively new to guitar techniques and music theory. I was watching a YouTube tutorial on playing Turkish March, I faced this notation:

I'm wondering what is the arch connecting 5 to 7 means here and how one should play it? Also is there a name for this technique? It was
played at this timestamp. It also appears later in the video:

Which was played at this timestamp.

Slurs on guitar can be executed in differing ways.Basically they're playing the small headed note, then moving, in various ways, to the larger headed note the slur joins them to.
There could be a simple slide, where the small note is played by plucking, then slid (in either direction) to the larger note, without taking the fretting finger off between.
There could be a hammer-on, where the small note is played, then again, usually without moving that finger, the main note is literally hammered on to its fret with another fretting finger.
There could be a pull-off, where the small note is the higher of the two. This needs another finger to be already on the main fret, and the small (grace) note is played by r.h., and that fretting finger pulls sideways from its fret to the lower one.
There could be ( in certain circumstances) a bend up or let down, which are pretty well self explanatory. Play the lower ,small note, then bend the string sideways to sound the main one. A let down requires a pre-bend - an odd term, in my opinion, but it means fret the main note, but bend it up to the small note, before plucking it, then let the tension down to the main note below.
Generally speaking these grace notes are a semitone or tone away from the main notes which follow, so it's never far to go. It's almost like 'oops, I've made a mistake and landed on the wrong fret, let's correct it!'

The curved line in the staff notation is called a "slur"; it means different things for different instruments, but the common element is that it specifies a legato transition between the notes that it joins (which may be more than two).
The first note being smaller, it is a "grace note"; it is customary to join such notes to the main note with a slur.

The arch line is a "slur."
The smaller font size note, the first of the two slurred notes, is a "grace note", which is a kind of ornamental decoration of the second note, the "main" note.
A slur can connect two adjacent notes or span a long series of notes.
Notes enclosed by the slur should be played connected, without separation. Long slurs can also be used to delineate phrases.
@Tim's answer provides a good list of guitar specific techniques you could use to execute the slur.
One thing to note, the main reason I added another answer, is whoever produce the score you posted decided to present both staff and tablature notation, but despite being able to give tablature notation for techniques like slides and hammers, they chose not to provide such signs. That could be just lazy editing, or it could mean they deliberately want you to have the latitude to choose how you execute the slur. In the case of the latter, the "how to" part of your question does not have one exclusive answer.
FWIW, in the video the slur is executed as a "hammer on."
Music theory wise, considering melody and harmony, the grace note A is a non-chord tone while the B is the chord tone, where the chord at that point in the music is an E major triad. A non-chord grace note slurred to a chord tone on the beat is a very common melodic decoration device.
Knowing this is a guitar arrangement of music originally for piano, and continuing the theme of latitude to interpret music, it might interest you to see the original score...


Notice how the beginning melody makes copious use of grace notes where the guitar arrangement gives them as normal sixteenth notes, and the original uses two grace notes for the slur you asked about, where the guitar arrangement gives them as single grace notes. I think this underscores the idea you can approach the guitar arrangement with some flexibility.

It's quite fast, but it seems to be either hammer-on (going up) or pull-off (going down). Here's a video that explains both.

Going from the fifth to the seventh fret is a hammer-on.

@PiedPiper Yes; and going from the 10th fret to the 9th, and from the 9th to the 7th (as per the second line of music), are pull-offs.  So the music uses both techniques.

@gidds Thanks for the clarification. I realized that there is also a slur between three notes too in the video (played at this moment). I'm wondering if it is also a hammer-on.

@user1380196 Considering it goes 0-1-0, it should be hammer-on and then pull-off in quick succession. (Not that I could make it out of the hands at this speed what the player's doing.)

It is, indeed, an open string played, which then gets a hammer-on to fret 1, and a pull-off back to the open string. Thanks to Divizna!!

The small note is technically called an Acciaccatura. It is one of several types of so called grace notes.
You see that it is an Acciaccatura because there is slash on the stem of the note. This kind of grace note leaves the main emphasis on the main note - it is sort of a small ornament on the main note. Rythmically it is generally played before the beat, the main note then comes exactly on the beat. (Historically there have been variations, but before the beat is mostly the universal use today).

Yes, but they are asking about the significance of the slur. Which may not necessarily be used with all acciaccatura.
